# Making new instances of a [generic type] using variables

Tags: c#, wpf, coding-style, instance-variables

```
  if (comboBox.Text == "Report 1 Name")
    {
        Reports.reportDelete report = new Reports.reportDelete();
        Preview.DocumentSource = report;
        report.CreateDocument();
    }
    else
    {
        Reports.reportDelete2 report = new Reports.reportDelete2();
        Preview.DocumentSource = report;
        report.CreateDocument();
    }
```

so say I had 100 reportDelete's, this way of writing this code is a not optimal. I was thinking of making a function that takes a variable name based of the combobox.Text and somehow pass it to make a new instance. only thing is im not sure how I can do that or if its even possible.

psuedo of what im trying to accomplish.

```
Reports.(combobox.Text) report = new Reports.(comboboxText());
Preview.DocumentSource = report;
report.CreateDocument();
```

Comment: If you start using MVVM you will find your code becomes far cleaner, simpler, more testable and more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

A simply solution is to ensure every `ReportDelete` class implements an `IReportDelete` interface and use a `Dictionary`:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, IReportDelete> ReportFactory =
    new Dictionary<string, IReportDelete>
    {
        { "Report 1 Name", new ReportDelete1() },
        { "Report 2 Name", new ReportDelete2() }, 
        ...
    };
```

Then replace you sequence of `if`'s with:

```
var report = ReportFactory[comboBox.Text];
Preview.DocumentSource = report;
report.CreateDocument();
```

Comment: Why have a func as the value and not simply the instance?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, good point: I was definitely over-engineering there.

Answer (score 1):

Could you make the reportDelete class more generic by passing in the report name?

```
public class reportDelete
{
    public string ReportName { get; private set; }

    public reportDelete(string reportName)
    {
        ReportName = reportName;
    }
}

...

Preview.DocumentSource = reportDelete(combobox.Text);
report.CreateDocument();
```